# upload custom wordpress theme to website instead of the current one

Tags: wordpress

Good Evening
the task is to replace new wordpress theme with new design with current old wordpres theme
the new theme is ready and test on my laptop on localhost
what should i do to upload it correctly ?

Comment: Hi Hema, I see no technical issue here! just refer to the wordpress docs: https://wordpress.com/support/themes/uploading-setting-up-custom-themes/

Answer (score 0):

Compress the theme into a zip file, and just upload it via the Wordpress Dashboard....

Appearance -> Themes -> then click on "Add New" -> then click on "Upload Theme"